# If I change the numbers into the if statement what the result whould be?

Tags: javascript

If I change the numbers into the if statement what the result whould be?

```js
function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
```

Comment: Different.  What have you tried?  What is your problem?

Comment: why asking, I guess you can simply try it out.

Comment: `you can simply try it out` - don't - in this context (HTTP): have a search engine point you to information about these specific values (which shouldn't appear in any source code as numeric literals in the 1st place).

Answer (score 1):

Beyond you being short two '}'s, it would be that nothing would happen, since then, most likely

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
```

wouldn't be processed, and your HTML wouldn't be enriched with the response text of whichever web service you're calling?

Comment: Don't know why this got a downvote.  It seems to answer the question.

Comment: i didn't downvote. but i guess if the 200 (succesfull http status code) will be changed to something like 999. the element with the id "demo" will never ve filled with the dynamic value. so a change could make a big change here.

Comment: Thank y so what should i do?

Comment: I think that's what @Steffen means by "nothing would happen."

Comment: @JimGamezz what is your intension for making a change?

Comment: @RickHitchcock oh you're right I got it wrong. yes then the answer is correct.

Comment: after the curly brackets there is a open and a send methods i just show you a part of the project. Btw this code is from w3schools

Comment: @snap I just want to see the result if i change the numbers

Comment: @JimGamezz why do you want to change the numbers. with which numbers  you want to replace them?

Comment: @JimGamezz change them to what? 200 is required, since it indicates a successful HTTP response. You could change 4, but then you most likely wouldn't satisfy both criterion, as I think only state 4 in ajax has a http response code..